# Align margin xcode 7.0 grey, no margin constraints update

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm having hard time to understand how the `autolayout margins` works.

I would like to put a `TextView` and `Button` horizontly centered and spaced from the margins (I'm actually following the apple tutorial on swift, but I'd like to understand these things).

When I click on `pin butt`on`, the`align`is greyed-out, and also the align button` doesn't show me any clickable option.

So, which is the problem? Is this the aim of these buttons?

And more, if I add left constraints, I can't see any changes.

I have already clicked on `Reset to suggested constraints`, and the red constraints disappeared but no changes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For pinning your text view and button to the horizontal center, click the button to the left of the one you have selected in your first photo, then check "Horizontally in container". Horizontal & vertical center align to container are the only options available if you have one view selected. The others will only work if you have multiple views selected and you would like to align their edges, centers, tops, bottoms, etc. You can see this by shift clicking 2 views: Those items will no longer be greyed out.

Here's an image of where to find the center align:
[image]

Comment: thanks for answering. 
Anyway, when I click on the button you write about, there are all the options grey, so I can't select them.
My poor connection didn't add the image with the not clickable options you talk about.

Comment: Ok, I added a photo to clarify. You also must remember to have a view selected when you click this button

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If so, accept the answer. If not, let me know what's going wrong

Comment: Sorry man, for my late answer. Anyway also selecting my view, and changing the numbers in the field you talk about, I can't see any changes. 
More, if I reselect the view and re-click this button, I see again the value of the "horizontally in container" equal to 0.

Comment: My problem is that, I can't center the view horizontally, because there is always no space between the left side of superview and my view.

I'm trying everything with no luck

Comment: You have to click the checkbox as well when you change the field

Comment: I know this. I swear I click the checkbox and change the size, but nothing changes. I'm going crazy